# WebFlux newbe troubles

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, webclient, spring-webflux, flux

I'm trying to startup simple Spring WebFlux based app and facing with strange trouble.

I return Flux from the server side, subsribe to the returned Flux on the client side with WebClient and expects obtain infinite stream of numbers.

But instead of that I get error

> org.springframework.core.codec.DecodingException: JSON decoding error:
> Cannot deserialize instance of `long` out of START_OBJECT token;
> nested exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
> deserialize instance of `long` out of START_OBJECT token  at [Source:
> UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]

Actually I get a map one time, instead of Long sequence

> {scanAvailable=true, prefetch=-1}

Could omeone tell me please, what wrong in my code *(Kotlin)* is?

Thanks in advance!

**Rest Controller**

```
@RestController
class Endpoint {

    @GetMapping(value = ["/pingpong"], produces = [MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE])
    suspend fun pingPong(): Flux<Long> {
        return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .map {
                    println("Emit $it")
                    it
                }
    }

}
```

**Client**

```
class ClientWrapper() {
    private val client = WebClient.create()

    fun start() {
        client.get()
                .uri("http://127.0.0.1:8888/pingpong")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(Long::class.java)
                .doOnError {
                    println(it)
                }.subscribe {
                    println("Answer: $it")
                }
    }
}
```

**Maven deps.**

```
    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.12.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0-M1</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-reactor</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0-M1</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.projectreactor.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>reactor-kotlin-extensions</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
                <version>2.11.3</version>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: What if you change `PostMapping` to `GetMapping`? As I know, `text/event-stream` works only with `GET` method

Comment: Hi Alexander,

Unfortunately not, it didn't help :(

But I edited the question in accoring to your remark

Comment: your endpoint is producing json and you are trying to deserialise that to a Long in the web client code. Jackson fails as it cannot deserialise json to a Long.

Comment: Just remove suspend I don’t think you need that there and then give it a shot.

Comment: @nicholasnet
Nicholas, you are absolutely right!
Everything works ok after I removed **suspend** keyword.

But it's strange thing for me, coz it's stated that Spring WebFlux supports kotlin coroutines.

Comment: You are right it supports Kotlin coroutine but you are mixing Mono/Flux with coroutine you need to stick with one. For more information please look at Spring documentation https://spring.io/blog/2019/04/12/going-reactive-with-spring-coroutines-and-kotlin-flow

Comment: @nicholasnet Thanks a lot!